# Django Email Confirmation activation view not working

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I am trying to set up an email confirmation for my django application. This is the activation URL:

```
url(r'^activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', activate, name='activate'),
```

and this is the activate view:

```
def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = get_user_model().objects.get(pk=uid)
    except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, get_user_model().DoesNotExist):
        user = None

    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.email_confirmed = True
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('profile')
    else:
        return render(request, 'email/invalid_token.html')
```

This is the error I am getting:

`TypeError at /activate/MzQ/4se-cb054dd0a60fb9f85110/
activate() got an unexpected keyword argument 'uidb64'`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have another function called activate somewhere?

Comment: Fixed it, thanks for the help. 1 question though, the activate function I had was below the one that it was meant to be using, why did it default to that one instead of the one higher up in the code?

Comment: Because Python files are executed in order, and the second definition overwrote the first in the module's namespace.

Comment: Right ok, thanks for your help!